# GeckoFx not displaying page correctly

Tags: c#, firefox, geckofx, predix

I'm using the GeckoFX winforms control in a .Net app to display a Predix Platform app. Not all of the components in the page are rendering, and the Javascript redirects aren't working. But everything loads fine in the latest version of Firefox.

Note that I'm using the binaries from https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeckoFX/ instead of initializing Xpcom using the Firefox dir. If I point Xpcom to my Firefox dir I get these errors:

> Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented:
>   permissionDBPDir A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   Geckofx-Core.dll Error: 6/12/2017 10:10:09
>   AMMainUnhandled
>   Exception: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) Audit: 6/12/2017 10:10:09
>   AMMainStack
>   Trace:    at Gecko.nsIServiceManager.GetServiceByContractID(String
>   aContractID, Guid& aIID)    at
>   Gecko.Xpcom.GetService[TInterfaceType](String contractID) in
>   D:\temp\ddfb20c\Geckofx-Core\Xpcom.cs:line 745    at
>   Gecko.DefaultPromptFactory.Init() in
>   D:\temp\ddfb20c\Geckofx-Core\PromptService.cs:line 79    at
>   Gecko.PromptFactoryFactory.Init() in
>   D:\temp\ddfb20c\Geckofx-Core\PromptService.cs:line 60    at
>   Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(String binDirectory) in
>   D:\temp\ddfb20c\Geckofx-Core\Xpcom.cs:line 381    at
>   XiboClient.MainForm.InitializeXibo() in
>   c:\Users\220023166\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\xibo-dotnetclient-1.8.1\MainForm.cs:line 165    at
>   XiboClient.MainForm..ctor() in c:\Users\220023166\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2010\Projects\xibo-dotnetclient-1.8.1\MainForm.cs:line 156
>   at XiboClient.Program.RunClient() in
>   c:\Users\220023166\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\xibo-dotnetclient-1.8.1\Program.cs:line 136    at
>   XiboClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\220023166\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\xibo-dotnetclient-1.8.1\Program.cs:line 118

Is there a security setting or something I might be missing in order to get this to work? Or is there a way I can view the webpage console through GeckoFX? I've inspected the page with Fiddler and it looks like all of the elements are loading correctly.